# Really simple loop in MATLAB but it just don't work

Tags: matlab, loops

I am *really* new to MATLAB and I am struggling to see why this code isn't working.

```
x = 0; 
for i=1:15
    x = x+1;
    for y=1:3
        for z=1:5
            img=cell2mat(TopStims(y,z));
            subplot(5,3,x)
            image(img)
            title(TopNames(y,z))
            axis off+
        end
    end
end
```

what I want to create is a 5*3 subplot of 15 images, taking the TopStims as my images and using  this loop to index into each one. But when I do it, it is writing over it so I get the image and title of TopStims(1,3) 15 times, and I just can't see why.

Halp

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to move the `x` updating into the innermost loop (and then your `for i` loop is unnecessary):

```
x = 0;
for y = 1:3
    for z = 1:5
        x = x + 1;
        img = cell2mat(TopStims(y,z));
        subplot(5,3,x)
        image(img)
        title(TopNames(y,z))
        axis off
    end
end
```

Comment: @user3078374 Are you sure your `TopStims` and `TopNames` variables contain different images/titles?

Comment: actually now it seems to be performing the y loop but I am now getting "Index exceeds matrix dimensions." message.

Comment: @user3078374 So... what was the problem? How did you solve it?

Comment: Oh a very silly moment where yours was actually right but I had just inverted the x and y vectors. Sorry, Silly me